# Collections2.filter method not satisfying with arguments passed

Tags: java, arraylist, guava

Am using `Collectins2.filter` method to filter values from `ArrayList of Arraylists` and it is giving the error. Its working perfectly with normal `ArrayList` to filter.

Please find my POJO class where am having `ArrayList of Arraylists`.

Menu.java

```
public class Menu {
  private String name;
  private String code;
  private String action;
  private String css;
  private String symbol;
  private String feature;
  private boolean visibleToExternal = true;
  private Set<String> permissions;

  private ArrayList<Menu> childMenus;
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>> newChildMenus=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>();

  public boolean hasChildMenus() {
    newChildMenus.add(subChildMenus);
    return newChildMenus !=null && !newChildMenus.isEmpty();

  }
}
```

Please find my `Predicate` method implementation.

```
 private Predicate<? super Menu> byRoleAndPermissions(final Role role, final Set<String> permissionsSet) {

        return new Predicate<Menu>() {
          @Override
          public boolean apply(Menu menu) {
            final boolean filterForExternalUser = !role.isRoleInternal() && !menu.isVisibleToExternal() && !(role.getCode().equals("DLR_ADMN") && menu.getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG"));
            // for dealer and dealer read only related changes : MDFY_USER_PRVG
            if(!role.isRoleInternal() && (role.getCode().equals("DLR") || role.getCode().equals("DLR_RD_ONLY")) && menu.getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG")){
                return true;
            }
            if (filterForExternalUser) {
              return false;
            }
            SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(menu.getPermissions(), permissionsSet);
            if (intersection.size() == 0) {
              return false;
            }
            if (menu.hasChildMenus()) {

                     menu.setChildMenus(new ArrayList<Menu>(filter(menu.getNewChildMenus(), byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet))));/// giving error - The method filter(Collection<E>, Predicate<? super E>) in the type Collections2 is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>, Predicate<capture#4-of ? super Menu>)
            }
            return true;
          }
        };
      }
```

Giving the below error during the `filter()` method implementation.

```
The method filter(Collection<E>, Predicate<? super E>) in the type Collections2 is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>, Predicate<capture#4-of ? super Menu>)
```

**Update 1**

Please find the code that i have been modified. but still am getting some errors `Return type for the method is missing`

```
 private Predicate<? super ArrayList<Menu>> byRoleAndPermissions(final Role role, final Set<String> permissionsSet) {

        return new Predicate<ArrayList<Menu>>() {
          @Override
          public boolean apply(ArrayList<Menu> menu) {

            Predicate<? super ArrayList<Menu>> predicate = byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet);
            final boolean filterForExternalUser = !role.isRoleInternal() && !menu.get(0).isVisibleToExternal() && !(role.getCode().equals("DLR_ADMN") && menu.get(0).getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG"));
            // for dealer and dealer read only related changes : MDFY_USER_PRVG
            if(!role.isRoleInternal() && (role.getCode().equals("DLR") || role.getCode().equals("DLR_RD_ONLY")) && menu.get(0).getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG")){
                return true;
            }
            if (filterForExternalUser) {
              return false;
            }
            SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(menu.get(0).getPermissions(), permissionsSet);
            if (intersection.size() == 0) {
              return false;
            }
            if (menu.hasChildMenus()) {

                     menu.setChildMenus(new ArrayList<Menu>(filter(Collection<E> collection, Predicate<? super E> predicate))); // errors coming here
            }
            return true;
          }
        };
      }
```

Comment: Why would it work? You need to pass a `Predicate<? super ArrayList<Menu>>`.

Comment: @YassinHajaj No, because: 1. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>` is a `Collection<E>`; 2. So `E` is `ArrayList<Menu>`; 3. so the second argument (`Predicate<? super E>`) becomes `Predicate<? super ArrayList<Menu>>`.

Comment: Indeed you're right :)

Comment: I have update my code., but still getting some errors. `Return type for the method is missing`

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the same generic inside of the method, so the method can't be invoked.

A way to make it more clear is to extract those to specific variables.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>> newChildMenus = menu.getNewChildMenus();
Predicate<? super Menu> predicate = byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet);
```

You can now clearly see that the type is not the same.
Still, your method awaits the same type to be able to work as its signature is

```
filter(Collection<E> collection, Predicate<? super E> predicate);
```

It would have worked if `ArrayList<Menu>` was a super class of `Menu` which is clearly not the case.

Comment: `menu.setChildMenus(new ArrayList<Menu>(filter(Collection<E> collection, Predicate<? super E> predicate)));` i changed my code like this., but still its throwing error `Multiple markers at this line`

Comment: @Karthikeyan Did you change your code to that? Why do you think it would work?

Comment: i was breaking my head more than a week. am not getting here the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your `Predicate` and their `Predicate` are different types!

I spent a long time scratching my head with this one too.  It turns out there's a very subtle gotcha: `Collections2.filter()`'s argument is `com.google.common.base.Predicate` while I was using `java.util.function.Predicate`.

There's actually a workaround mentioned in `com.google.common.base.Predicate`'s javadoc:

> To use a `java.util.function.Predicate` where a `com.google.common.base.Predicate` is expected, use the method reference `predicate::test`.

So I guess you need to write `filter(..., byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet)::test)`.